# Referencing components from within a v-stepper

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a v-stepper and want to collect results as I go along.  At the last stepper I want to use all those results to do something. The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
// MyStepper.vue
<v-stepper-content step="1">
  <SomeComponent ref="one"/>
  // This works so the ref is valid
  <v-btn text @click="this.$refs.one.runMethod()">Test</v-btn>
  <v-btn text @click="stepperNum++">Next</v-btn>
</v-stepper>
<v-stepper-content step="2">
  <SomeOtherComponent ref="two"/>
  // This works so the ref is valid
  <v-btn text @click="this.$refs.two.runMethod()">Test</v-btn>
  <v-btn text @click="stepperNum++">Next</v-btn>
</v-stepper>
<v-stepper-content step="3">
  <AnotherComponent v-if="canLoad"
   :one="$refs.one.results" 
   :two="$refs.two.results"/>
</v-stepper>

// SomeComponent.vue/SomeOtherComponent.vue
data: function() {
  return {
    results: [],
    stepperNum: 0
  }
}
methods: {
  runMethod() {
    console.log("Clicked");
  }
}
computed: {
  canLoad() {
    return this.stepperNum > 2;
  }
}

// AnotherComponent.vue
props: {
  one: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  },
  two: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
}
```

When i run that code I get a 't.$refs.one is undefined' message. I am assuming this is because everything is loading at the same time when the MyStepper.vue page is loaded.

Is there a way to prevent v-steppers from loading their bodies (aka AnotherComponent.vue) until the previous v-stepper has been complete? Is there a different strategy that should be used to achieve the desired functionality?

Update: I decided to watch the results inside the child component, and emit an event. The parent uses the emitted event to control the data and enable/disable next buttons, pass in the results to the third component, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** OP confirmed that there's no reactivity when using the `refs` contents for a computed property. Consider the first code block as a wrong approach. Use regular variables instead of refs.

---

I guess I would go for a computed property returning `true` when both refs are loaded:

```
computed: {
  canLoadThirdStep() {
    return (this.$refs.one && this.$refs.two)
  }
}
```

Then just use the returned value in a `v-if` to display `AnotherComponent`:

```
<AnotherComponent 
  v-if="canLoadThirdStep" 
  :one="$refs.one.results" 
  :two="$refs.two.results" 
/>
```

I hope this is what you wanted. Let me know if this works!

Comment: Hi, thanks!  It seems when I run that canLoadThirdStep never returns true

Comment: Hello! I don't know if the stepper does unmount the passed steps but it's worth checking it: can you log both refs right before the `return` statement in the computed property?

Comment: It looks like the computed only runs once on startup and returns undefined for both. . fwiw I updated the code in the op to add a v-btn to test that the ref is actually valid (which it is). Sidenote - It won't help ultimately, but I can modify the computed to check the stepper number instead of the refs.

Comment: Maybe refs can't trigger reactivity behavior, sorry I don't know much about this kind of refs use case. And yeah if you use the stepper number instead, it should be reactive since it's a regular variable.

Comment: I have no clue why it works, but changing the computed to watch the stepper  instead of the refs seems to work. Code updated  in OP

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 Okay so it might be true that refs themselves can't trigger any updates from Vue.js reactivity. It's a pretty interesting case though!